# Microsoft Advanced Hunting Query API works for some tables but not others in power BI

Tags: powerbi, securitycenter, advanced-threat-protection

I am using the following API call in Power BI to access Advanced Hunting data from 365.

https://api.securitycenter.windows.com/api/advancedqueries

Using this API works with some tables but not others in Power BI.

For example:

`DeviceEvents | limit 10` will bring back 10 results.

`AlertInfo | limit 10` returns a 400 Bad Request.

Both the above queries work successfully in the [advanced hunting tool](https://security.microsoft.com/v2/advanced-hunting) within 365 itself.

I have found that this is the same with a lot of other tables within the [Advanced Hunting Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/security/defender/advanced-hunting-schema-tables?view=o365-worldwide) as well, such as IdentityInfo and EmailEvents to name a few more.

Is there something obvious that I am missing? I thought perhaps that it was the number of items being returned, hence the limit 10 but that didn't resolve the issue either.

This is an example of [Microsofts Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/api-power-bi?view=o365-worldwide) around the Power BI specific query methods, but has not helped to resolve the issue.

```
    let
    AdvancedHuntingQuery = "DeviceEvents | where ActionType contains 'Anti' | limit 20",

    HuntingUrl = "https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/advancedqueries",

    Response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(HuntingUrl, [Query=[key=AdvancedHuntingQuery]])),

    TypeMap = #table(
        { "Type", "PowerBiType" },
        {
            { "Double",   Double.Type },
            { "Int64",    Int64.Type },
            { "Int32",    Int32.Type },
            { "Int16",    Int16.Type },
            { "UInt64",   Number.Type },
            { "UInt32",   Number.Type },
            { "UInt16",   Number.Type },
            { "Byte",     Byte.Type },
            { "Single",   Single.Type },
            { "Decimal",  Decimal.Type },
            { "TimeSpan", Duration.Type },
            { "DateTime", DateTimeZone.Type },
            { "String",   Text.Type },
            { "Boolean",  Logical.Type },
            { "SByte",    Logical.Type },
            { "Guid",     Text.Type }
        }),

    Schema = Table.FromRecords(Response[Schema]),
    TypedSchema = Table.Join(Table.SelectColumns(Schema, {"Name", "Type"}), {"Type"}, TypeMap , {"Type"}),
    Results = Response[Results],
    Rows = Table.FromRecords(Results, Schema[Name]),
    Table = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Rows, Table.ToList(TypedSchema, (c) => {c{0}, c{2}}))

in Table
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with Microsoft who confirmed that only some tables were accessiable via the API that is in the documentation linked in my post. They provded a work around which was to use a slightly different API which I did not come across in my travels. The exerpt from the response is below:

> Therefore, I changed the Advanced hunting URL from https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com/api/advancedqueries to https://api.security.microsoft.com/api/advancedhunting from Power BI advanced Editor. (This may need you to sign in again from Power BI in Organizational account)

I can confirm that using this second API within Power BI has given me access to the additional Tables I was after.